# How do I view my crew title in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

In addition to the crew hierarchy, I noticed there is a title that goes along with your rank.  I see my current rank when I log into rockstar social club and go to the crew homepage for GTA Online.

How do I see the whole hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to see the whole Hierarchy of your crew via the Rockstar social club, **View your hierarchy** and **Manage your hierarchy**.

## To view the hierarchy of your crew:

**1) [Login to the Rockstar Social Club here](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/)**

**2) Click on the Crews link**

[image]

**3) Click on the crew's title that you want to view the hierarchy of (*you can be in multiple crews, but only one can be active at a time*)**.  The text will turn a different color when you mouse over it.  **Note**: I have *painted* over our crew as I am not looking to advertise in this answer (PM me if you would like to join).

[image]

**4) Click on Hierarchy**

[image]

**5) View your awesome hierarchy!**

[image]

## To manage your crew:

**1) After clicking the crews link (#1 already shown above), click on Manage Crew.**  Either link shown in the picture will work.
[image]

**2) Click on the Hierarchy tab, and manage your crew!**

[image]

If you are interested in the actual rank titles your Crew leader specifies, you can view that under manage (if you have the previlage to do so) and at the bottom of the page.  Ours looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks.  i scrolled to the bottom of hierarchy but didn't see the rank titles.  guess i don't have access to view them